# How can i firebase initialize from first in the same project?

Tags: reactjs

I am using firebase authentication in react project. I  want to firebase initialize from first. How can i do it? I am tried but failed to complete initialized.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

first of all, `build` folder and`.firebase` , .`firebaserc` , `firebase.json` , `package-lock.json` , `yarn.lock` ( if exist ) delete them.

Then re command those.

```
firebase init
```

**and follow the steps as you want to deploy.**

What do you want to use as your public directory?   build
Configure as a single-page app (rewrite all URLs to /index.html)?  Yes
Set up automatic builds and deploys with GitHub?   No
File build/index.html already exists. Overwrite?   Yes